# Get Start Date of the Occurrence that is being accepted from a recurring appointment

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to forward appointments from one email account to another.

I managed this for a single appointment.

For recurring appointments, when I accept, instead of the occurrence date, it gets the first date of the series.

```vb
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents newAppt As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim objNS As NameSpace
  Set objNS = Application.Session
  Set newAppt = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items
  Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub


Private Sub newAppt_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)

Dim I As Boolean 'control parameter to avoid unexpected duplications
i = True 
Dim fwdAppt As Object
Set fwdAppt = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

Debug.Print Item.RecurrenceState

If (Item.ResponseStatus = olResponseAccepted And Item.RequiredAttendees <> "email@domain.com") Then 'condition to avoid infinite loop
    With fwdAppt
        If (i = True) Then
            .Recipients.Add "email@domain.com"
            .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
            .subject = Item.subject
            .Start = Item.Start
            .End = Item.End
            .Duration = Item.Duration
            .Location = Item.Location
            .Body = "Required: " & Chr(13) & Item.RequiredAttendees & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "Optional: " & Chr(13) & Item.OptionalAttendees & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "Body: " & Item.Body
            .Send
            .Delete 'delete the forwarded appointment item to keep only the original in the calendar
            i = False
        End If
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

`Debug.Print Item.RecurrenceState` returns '1' which means the appointment is a master appointment, even when I open and accept a specific occurrence and select to open just that occurrence instead of the series.